# Xamarin: Mock Location Crashes

Tags: xamarin

I am working on an app, that reads the users GPS coordinates and changes them just a little bit to then set the new location as mock location. Now this all works but this part of the code crashes my build:

```
    public bool SetMockLocation()
    {
        bool success = false;

        var location = new Location("Test");
        _locationManager.AddTestProvider("Test", false, false, false, false, false, false, false, Power.Low, Android.Hardware.SensorStatus.AccuracyHigh);
        location.Latitude = Add700ToCoordinates();
        location.Longitude = GlobalLongitude;
        _locationManager.SetTestProviderLocation("Test", location);

        return success; 
     }
```

I unfortunately have not been able to find much detail about this at all, all I know that my app Crahses and Visual STudio says:

Java.Lang.SecurityException: GetLocation.GetLocation from uid 10303 not allowed to perform MOCK_LOCATION

So, I decided not to debug the app from my laptop, but to start it from the phone - now with this app set as "Allow mock location".

Here is where it gets wired: Even though my app appears here (yes, I added the permissions) - when I click on it, my phone shows another app that I also have installed and that appears in this menu to be set as mock location. No matter how much I click on my app, my phone always takes the other app.

Nevertheless, as soon as I click on my app and launch it from my phone it simple crashes. Now, did I do something wrong? Im really out of ideas...

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

The error:

> Java.Lang.SecurityException: GetLocation.GetLocation from uid 10303 not allowed to perform MOCK_LOCATION

Reveals that you have not asked for permission to mock the location.

You need to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

To your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: thanks. ofcourse i already had this permission added to my manifest. yet, i get this error. however, i ONLY get this error, when i debug the app directly from xamarin. if i start it from my phone, the app starts crashing only when i click on the button to edit the gps coordinates of my phone.... any other idea?